# "preg_split" with Except Numbers

Tags: php, regex

I can print the first letters of the codes but I do not want it to involve numbers.

**Code:**

```
$str= "This is a example word and 3512987 ID registered.."
$words = preg_split("/(\s|\-|\(|\s+|\.)/", $str);
```

**Print:**

```
TIAEWA3IR --> This is correct but I want full print digit. For example:

TIAEWA3512987IR --> this version with full-digit
```

For this, Which I need a Regex code?

Comment: Could you please clarify: you want to get a string that consists of first letters in words and digit chunks?

Comment: What about [`preg_match_all('~\b[a-zA-Z]|\d+~', $str, $matches);`](https://ideone.com/9ffeg6)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, First letters to be written but digits to be written completely

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, how can I print output normally as an array (echo format)?

Comment: Could you clarify the "print output normally as an array (echo format)" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get an array of first ASCII letters in words and chunks of 1+ digits from a string, use

```
preg_match_all('~\b[a-zA-Z]|\d+~', $str, $matches);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/9ffeg6):

```
$str = "This is a example word and 3512987 ID registered..";
preg_match_all('~\b[a-zA-Z]|\d+~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

You may later `implode` the array or use other manipulations as you see  fit (e.g. `implode("", array_map('ucfirst', $matches[0]))`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/S7RYT0)).

**Details**:

- `\b[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter preceded with a word boundary
- `|` - or
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

**To make the regex work with any UNICODE letters**, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{L}` [Unicode category class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) letter pattern, and add the `u` UNICODE modifier that will enable `preg_` function to correctly treat the input string as a Unicode string and the PCRE egnine will also treat `\p{L}` and `\b` as Unicode aware patterns:

```
preg_match_all('~\b\p{L}|\d+~u', $str, $matches);
                   ^^^^^     ^
```

Note that `\d` will also start matching digits that are not plain ASCII digits from `0` to `9`. Then, if you want to prevent it, use `[0-9]+` instead:

```
preg_match_all('~\b\p{L}|[0-9]+~u', $str, $matches);
                         ^^^^^
```

Comment: Hi again, How can I prevent the insertion of quotation mark?
For example: `Hello Wiktor, sample word's okey` -> `hwswo`.. Do not accept quotation marks (word's), Is this possible?

Comment: @HadiOradan Try [`'~\b(?<!\p{L}')[a-zA-Z]|\d+~'`](https://regex101.com/r/q2sd7t/1)

Comment: You're Regex Master! Thank you again.

Comment: Now I need Russian alphabet. I would like to ask you, does not recognize Russian letters. How can this be compatible in the Russian alphabet? Thank you!

Comment: Let's match all of them: `'~\b\p{L}|\d+~u'`

Comment: Master Wiktor! Dzięki !! :)

Comment: I added more details to the answer.